# creating vbs script to install .bat file to remote IP

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I have a .bat file that i need run on remote IP's on our network. What i would like to do is prompt for the 10.x.x portion of the IP address, then have the script preform a loop which starts at .1 and continues to .254, that way the .bat file is pushed to 10.x.x.1 - 10.x.x.254

So far this is what ive got:

```
Dim WshShell
set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")

strUserInput = InputBox("enter network" )

Wshshell.exec("cmd /k CD ../directory/file.bat" & strUserInput)
```

If i manually open up a cmd and navigate to the correct directory and run file.bat 10.x.x.x, the .bat file will run on the remote machine if its on the network.

Comment: Are you just looking for a loop from 1-254?

Comment: Well im having trouble getting the entered text string to be appended to the first part of the code.

Comment: I haven't used vb in a while, try a MsgBox to see what you're missing: MsgBox( "cmd /k CD ../directory/file.bat" & strUserInput )

Comment: not sure what you mean by a MsgBox. i tried 
Wshshell.MsgBox("cmd /k CD ../bit9/deploy_bit9.bat" & strUserInput) but it errored out and said 'object doesnt support this property or method'

Comment: isn't there a problem, that you don't have a space at the end of the "cmd /k ... file.bat" string?

Comment: Good catch John, there does need to be a space there. Also, is there a way i can force the cmd window to stay open?? it keeps closing before i can even see anything. 

btw thanks soo much for your help everyone

Answer (score 0):

This worked for creating and showing the string correctly:

```
Sub test()
    Dim location As String
    location = InputBox("enter network")
    MsgBox ("cmd /k CD ../directory/file.bat" & location)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do i have to include 'as string' when i declare that variable?